# MySQL: "Integrity constraint violation" "Column cannot be null" for tinyint, but not for smallint

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the error I am getting:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'financial_access' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sss_users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `roles`, `church`, `financial_access`, `church_sponsor`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Debiprasad, Sahoo, my-email-id@gmail.com, y$ohh67yNFjzYCbhYUrEJ2u.C.oe9xuOndhG2m7pFs7P5pVIwV9MxwC, administrator, , , , 2014-06-23 15:51:50, 2014-06-23 15:51:50))

- `church` field is `smallint(5) UNSIGNED not null`.
- `financial_access` is `tinyint(1) default '0' not null`.

Why I am getting the error for the `tinyint(1)` field, but not for the `smallint(5)` field, which accepts the empty string in the query so easily?

Comment: I suspect the error message just shows one error column, not all columns with errors. So if you fix `financial_access`, you'll get an error for `church`.

Comment: No, I fixed the error by providing '0' for both 'financial_access' and 'church_sponsor'. But I am not getting any exception for church. It's accepting null value in the query and saves the record in the database as 0.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you're getting that syntax allowed. I get a syntax error when I try to put two commas in a row in an `INSERT` query.